# Problems getting and setting data on QTableWidgets

Tags: qt, qtablewidget, qtablewidgetitem

I have two QTableWidgets and I'm trying to synchronize them as an exercise to figure out how to get / set data.

The current code I have is:

```
void MainWindow::on_tableWidget_2_cellChanged(int row, int column)
{
    double value = ui->tableWidget_2->itemAt(row,column)->text().toDouble();
    ui->tableWidget->itemAt(row,column)->setData(Qt::UserRole, value);
}
```

I have also tried:

```
void MainWindow::on_tableWidget_2_cellChanged(int row, int column)
{
    QString value = ui->tableWidget_2->itemAt(row,column)->text();
    ui->tableWidget->itemAt(row,column)->setText(value);
}
```

No matter what, the QString returned from QTableWidgetItem::text() is an empty string. This happens regardless of whether or not there was any text before I attempted editing.

Not sure if it matters, but this is how I initialize the table:

```
QTableWidgetItem * tableItem;
for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
ui->tableWidget->insertRow(i);
ui->tableWidget_2->insertRow(i);

tableItem = new QTableWidgetItem();
ui->tableWidget->setItem(i,0,tableItem);
tableItem = new QTableWidgetItem();
ui->tableWidget->setItem(i,1,tableItem);

tableItem = new QTableWidgetItem();
ui->tableWidget_2->setItem(i,0,tableItem);
tableItem = new QTableWidgetItem();
ui->tableWidget_2->setItem(i,1,tableItem);
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I changed the initialization code so each cell in tableWidget_2 contains the string "8" upon startup. Now when I get the value from the cell it's always "8", but setting the value in the other tableWidget still does nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`void QTableWidgetItem::setData ( int role, const QVariant & value )`

You maybe should try like this:

```
ui->tableWidget->itemAt(row,column)->setData(Qt::UserRole, QVariant(value));
```

and get back the data using like this:

```
ui->tableWidget->itemAt(row,column)->data().toReal();
```

Comment: QTableWidgetItem::data(..) takes an int for a role, so I just called with Qt::UserRole. Now whenever I get the data it comes out as 0. Setting it still does nothing.

Comment: Changing the role in both the getter and setter to "Qt::DisplayRole" works.